# Trying to store float within NSInteger (or find out how to store it in something else)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgfloat

I am trying to store the height of the screen in **NSInteger**.

```
NSInteger *screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

I also tried to store it in **NSString** and **NSNumber**, but there is always an error that says *Initializing 'NSInteger*' (aka 'int*') with an expression of incompatible type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')*.
I will go back to get the screen size from whatever I store it in later in the code, but what can I store a float in?

Answer (score 2):

`NSInteger` is typdef of basic `int`.

You need to use

```
NSInteger screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

**Note: self.view.frame.size.height returns you `float`* so why not to use float.

Also unless you really want a pointer to an integer never use `NSInteger*`

---

Edit:

In case you want `NSNumber` then

```
NSNumber *screenHeight = @(self.view.frame.size.height); //box the value to NSNumber
```

If you want it an `NSString` then

```
NSString *screenHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height];
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `NSInteger` is a typedef of `int` only on 32-bit hardware. On 64-bit, `NSInteger` is a typedef of `long`.

Answer (score 1):

remove the '*' NSInteger is a primitive type.

```
NSInteger screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store it as object (i.e. to add it to an array), use

```
NSNumber *screenHeight =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.frame.size.height];
```